# How to iterate through very large text file separated by semicolons?

Tags: python, file-processing, text-processing

If I want to iterate through a text file line-by-line, here is how I do it:

```
for curr_line in open('my_file.txt', 'r').readlines()
    print '|' + curr_line + '|'
```

If I want to iterate through a text based on semi-colon separators, here is how I do it:

```
for curr_line in open('my_file.txt', 'r').read().split(';')
    print '|' + curr_line + '|'
```

If I want to iterate through a very large text file line-by-line, here is how I do it:

```
for curr_line in open('my_file.txt', 'r').xreadlines()
    print '|' + curr_line + '|'
```

But how can I iterate through a very large text file based on semi-colon separators? It is 7+ gigabytes so I cannot read the whole thing into memory.

Below is the sample input file `my_file.txt`:

```
AAAA;BBBBB
BB;CCC;
DDDDD
D
D;
EEEE;F
```

Here is the output I want to see based on the snippets above:

```
|AAAA|
|BBBBB
BB|
|CCC|
|DDDDD
D
D|
|EEEE|
|F|
```

Comment: What's the criteria to insert the `|`s? To bracket series of the same item? Is it important to maintain the `\n` like the B's and D's? Can they not be in the same line?

Answer (score 1):

The method `.readlines()` reads the entire file into a list. This may not be practicable with a 7GB file.

Given the example added, you can use [mmap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html) and a regex to do whole file regex matches without loading the entire file:

```
import re 
import mmap 

with open(fn,'r+b') as f_in:
    mm = mmap.mmap(f_in.fileno(), 0)    
    for m in re.finditer('([^;]*)', mm):
        txt=m.group(1)
        if txt:
            print('|{}|'.format(txt))
```

With the example, prints:

```
|AAAA|
|BBBBB
BB|
|CCC|
|
DDDDD
D
D|
|
EEEE|
|F|
```

Comment: No, this is not right. A semi-colon separated entry might span across multiple lines. Your solution assumes that lines semi-colons are separators within each line.

Comment: What character defines a 'line'? Maybe add an example of the input and output.

Comment: Dawg, I just did so. Sorry my original question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Solution added based on the example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "reader" object that will read blocks (with a size of your choosing) from your file, and emit semicolon-separated items as they're found:

```
class MyReader:
    def __init__(self, handle, delim, read_size=512):
        self.handle = handle
        self.delim = delim
        self.read_size = read_size


    def __iter__(self):
        buffer = []
        while True:
            block = self.handle.read(self.read_size)
            if not block: break     # Reached EOF

            while block:
                (before, sep, block) = block.partition(self.delim)
                buffer.append(before)

                if sep:             # Separator was found, yield the buffer
                    yield ''.join(buffer)
                    buffer = []

        # We broke free, flush the buffer and return (explicit)
        yield ''.join(buffer)
        return
```

Which you might use, for example:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    reader = MyReader(f, ';')

    for chunk in reader:
        print(repr(chunk))
```

**Output:**

```
'AAAA'
'BBBBB\nBB'
'CCC'
'\nDDDDD\nD\nD'
'\nEEEE'
'F'
```

Comment: I think the `\n`s in front of the D and E might not meet his requirements, take another look at his expected output.

Comment: I mean, the `\n` characters come *after* semicolons / are exactly where they are in the file.  I went by the text in the question and spirit of the output instead of the exact "expected output" because there are a few obvious errors in there (sets of two pipes separated by only newline characters when there are no similar sequences of semicolons)